# Optimizar código para no sobrepasar el tamaño "long code"

Tags: java, android-studio

Como podría optimizar o dividir en más métodos este código para no sobrepasar el tamaño "long code":

```
 lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.item_list_trafico, R.id.codigo_token,tokens);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener ( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String Seleccion= parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            if (Seleccion.equals("Comportarse indebidamente en la circulación causando peligro a las personas"))           {
                String Seleccion_Mesoamerica = (String)lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Intent visorDetalles = new Intent ( view.getContext (), detalles_trafico.class );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "NORMA", datos[0][0] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "ARTICULO", datos[0][1] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "APARTADO", datos[0][2] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "OPCION", datos[0][3] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "PUNTOS", datos[0][4] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "CALIFICACION", datos[0][5] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "RESPONSABLE", datos[0][6] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "CUANTIA", datos[0][7] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "DESCRIPCION", datos[0][8] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "COMENTARIOS", datos[0][9] );
                showpublicidad ();
                startActivity ( visorDetalles );      }
            else if(Seleccion.equals("Comportarse indebidamente en la circulación entorpeciendo la misma, causando perjuicios y molestias innecesarias a las personas o daños a los bienes"))
            {String Seleccion_Mesoamerica = (String)lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Intent visorDetalles = new Intent ( view.getContext (), detalles_trafico.class );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "NORMA", datos[1][0] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "ARTICULO", datos[1][1] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "APARTADO", datos[1][2] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "OPCION", datos[1][3] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "PUNTOS", datos[1][4] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "CALIFICACION", datos[1][5] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "RESPONSABLE", datos[1][6] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "CUANTIA", datos[1][7] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "DESCRIPCION", datos[1][8] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "COMENTARIOS", datos[1][9] );
                showpublicidad ();
                startActivity ( visorDetalles );}
            else if(Seleccion.equals("Conducir de forma temeraria"))
            {String Seleccion_Mesoamerica = (String)lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Intent visorDetalles = new Intent ( view.getContext (), detalles_trafico.class );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "NORMA", datos[2][0] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "ARTICULO", datos[2][1] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "APARTADO", datos[2][2] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "OPCION", datos[2][3] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "PUNTOS", datos[2][4] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "CALIFICACION", datos[2][5] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "RESPONSABLE", datos[2][6] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "CUANTIA", datos[2][7] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "DESCRIPCION", datos[2][8] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "COMENTARIOS", datos[2][9] );
                showpublicidad ();
                startActivity ( visorDetalles );}

            else if(Seleccion.equals("Conducir sin la diligencia, precaución y no distracción necesarios para evitar todo daño propio o ajeno"))
            {String Seleccion_Mesoamerica = (String)lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Intent visorDetalles = new Intent ( view.getContext (), detalles_trafico.class );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "NORMA", datos[3][0] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "ARTICULO", datos[3][1] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "APARTADO", datos[3][2] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "OPCION", datos[3][3] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "PUNTOS", datos[3][4] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "CALIFICACION", datos[3][5] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "RESPONSABLE", datos[3][6] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "CUANTIA", datos[3][7] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "DESCRIPCION", datos[3][8] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "COMENTARIOS", datos[3][9] );
                showpublicidad ();
                startActivity ( visorDetalles );}
```

Así un montón de lineas más hasta que se ha sobrepasado el límite.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Claramente, visorDetalles cumple siempre un mismo patron de llenado. eso podria estar en otro metodo tranquilamente

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, como me sugerirías que hiciese ese método?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que veo, lo unico que cambias en cada if-else es la cadena que compruebas, y el numero que se asigna en cada elemento. Esto significa que cada cadena te aporta un `indice` para diferenciar lo que asignas en visorDetalles. Por tanto, podrias asignar una variable con el valor que corresponda, y hacer algo como:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String Seleccion= parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();                 
    int control;
    if (Seleccion.equals("Comportarse indebidamente en la circulación causando peligro a las personas")){
       control = 0;
    } else if(Seleccion.equals("Comportarse indebidamente en la circulación entorpeciendo la misma, causando perjuicios y molestias innecesarias a las personas o daños a los bienes")) { 
       control = 1;
    } else if(Seleccion.equals("Conducir de forma temeraria")) {
       control=2;
    } else if(Seleccion.equals("Conducir sin la diligencia, precaución y no distracción necesarios para evitar todo daño propio o ajeno")) {
       control = 3; 
    }

    String Seleccion_Mesoamerica = (String)lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
    Intent visorDetalles = new Intent ( view.getContext (), detalles_trafico.class );
    visorDetalles.putExtra ( "NORMA", datos[control][0] );
    visorDetalles.putExtra ( "ARTICULO", datos[control][1] );
    visorDetalles.putExtra ( "APARTADO", datos[control][2] );
    visorDetalles.putExtra ( "OPCION", datos[control][3] );
    visorDetalles.putExtra ( "PUNTOS", datos[control][4] );
    visorDetalles.putExtra ( "CALIFICACION", datos[control][5] );
    visorDetalles.putExtra ( "RESPONSABLE", datos[control][6] );                
    visorDetalles.putExtra ( "CUANTIA", datos[control][7] );
    visorDetalles.putExtra ( "DESCRIPCION", datos[control][8] );
    visorDetalles.putExtra ( "COMENTARIOS", datos[control][9] );
    showpublicidad ();
    startActivity ( visorDetalles );
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me parece admirable la facilidad que tenéis los programadores para resolver "problemas". Toda la tarde he estado liado buscando la manera de resolverlo. Los dicho muchas gracias por tu tiempo.